# Vim: Find and replace in a large project?

Tags: vim, replace

There's a way to replace all occurencies of a string in files in [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) using a combination of [args and argdo commands](http://www.ibrahim-ahmed.com/2008/01/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in.html). Unfortunately there's a drawback with this solution: It will open all files which may be a problem for large projects. Does anyone know more compact and memory efficient way?

Comment: Must you use vim? I'd use sed, it's a better tool for the job.

Comment: @GregHewgill I'd like to have a chance to confirm a particular change like `gc` flag in Vim regexp. Just using `sed -i` seems a bit dangerous to me.

Comment: If you're going to look at all the changes anyway, use sed and then inspect the resulting diff.

Comment: If your `sed` supports it, you can do `sed -i.bak`, which produces backup files, and (if you want) check the `diff`s.

Comment: @Kevin `-i.bak` is something I'd like to avoid in this particular case: there'll be many .bak files to be checked and removed.

Comment: @GregHewgill For a 50% change ratio inspecting the diff is just the same as the original problem, isn't it?

Comment: I was assuming you're using source control of some kind, where you can make the change and then diff against the previous revision. If you're not using source control, please start now.

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm using git and I always can checkout the previous version. But that doesn't help much if a file should be changed partly.

Comment: I would use sed, then `git add -p` to inspect every change. Then it's easy to throw away the changes you don't want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find projectfolder -type f -exec grep -Iq 'pattern' {} \; -exec vim {} +
```

Comment: There's a slight problem with this solution: `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal` which results in a broken console after quitting vim. The reason for that is that xargs runs its argument commands in an environment in which standard input is not the user's terminal. So I would suggest something of the form: `find projectfolder -type f -exec grep -Iq 'pattern' {} \; -print | xargs sh -c '</dev/tty vim $*'`

Comment: @nab Good point. After some testing, I found (surprisinly, to me at least) that changing the `-print0 | xargs ...` to  `-exec ... +` worked. It actually makes some sense, `find`  alone doesn't read stdin so its children can. It's the first functional difference between the two I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it (when I'm not using `perl`):

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec vim +'%s/OldName/NewName/gc' +'wq' {} \;
```

i.e. replace "OldName" with "NewName" in all "*.java" files, but prompt me for confirmation for each substitution.

Comment: Thanks! And how do you do it when you are using Perl?

Comment: `find . -name '*.java' -exec perl -i.BAK -wpe 's/OldName/NewName/g' {} \;` saves the old file with a ".BAK" extension so you can then review the changes with `diff`.